# How to convert 2020-08-20T12:02:02Z date into DD-MM-YYYY sql?

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to convert "2020-08-20T12:02:02Z" date into DD-MM-YYYY in the oracle database. The date should look like 20-08-2020. Please advise.

Comment: Dates are stored as dates, but you can chose how to display them when you SELECT from the table.

Comment: What is the datatype of the `2020-08-20T12:02:02Z` value, and what will you do with the output? Store it in a `date` column, or display it in a report/application?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below -

```
select to_char(
             to_date('2020-08-20T12:02:02Z','YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS"Z"'),
       'DD-MM-YYYY')
from dual
```

Comment: This assumes that the OP's data is a string; however the OP said that they have a "date".

Comment: To be fair, '2020-08-20T12:02:02Z' doesn't look like something you'd get from an actual date column. It seems more likely that it comes from a file or application and the OP doesn't know what an Oracle date is. I'm guessing of course, because it's an unwritten law that no question about date handling ever specifies the datatype.

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR: Use `TO_CHAR( column_name, 'DD-MM-YYYY' )` to explicitly format your `DATE` column.

---

A `DATE` column does not have a format; it is stored internally as 7-bytes (century, year-of-century, month, day, hour, minute and second respectively). It is not until a user interface tries to display the date that the displayed value is implicitly formatted based on the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` session parameter (and this can be set by any user at any time within their own session so multiple users can have multiple date formats and these implicit formats can be changed mid-session so you should **NEVER** rely on implicit formatting to give consistent output).

So, if you have a `DATE` and its value is `2020-08-20T12:02:02Z` then all you need to do is to format it when displaying it (using `TO_CHAR`) to not display the time component:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (
  column_name DATE
);

INSERT INTO table_name ( column_name )
  VALUES ( DATE '2020-08-20' + INTERVAL '12:02:02' HOUR TO SECOND );
```

Set the implicit format for dates:

```sql
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS"Z"';
```

Then:

```sql
SELECT column_name AS with_implicit_formatting,
       TO_CHAR( column_name, 'DD-MM-YYYY' ) AS with_explicit_formatting
FROM   table_name;
```

Outputs:

> ```
> WITH_IMPLICIT_FORMATTING | WITH_EXPLICIT_FORMATTING
> :----------------------- | :-----------------------
> 2020-08-20T12:02:02Z     | 20-08-2020
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=4492bcb4239ec7ed795e13a4ef2adb2a)*

---

Note: the `Z` format model implies the Zulu (`UTC+0`) time zone. However, dates do not store time zones; so if you want to store this time-zone information then you should be using a `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` data type rather than a `DATE` (and you may need to pay extra care when converting date-time values from a local time zone to `UTC+0` that you apply the correct time zone offset to convert to `UTC+0` and do not just take the date-time component and ignore the local time zone.